# Facing error 'NZOLEDB' provider is not registered on this local machine

Tags: odbc, netezza, aginity

I am using Aginity 4.8.0.2551(build 6/14/2016) for connecting Netezza server and the Netezza ODBC driver 6.0.2.0 but still i am getting the error when trying to connect data base server from visual studio platform

Error message: The 'NZOLEDB' provider is not registered on this local machine.

Even though the ODBC driver 6.0.2.0 is installed i am facing this issue. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to install ODBC and OLEDB drivers separately. Having one is no guarantee for the other

Comment: Can you please provide me a link from where i can get OLEDB driver?